# system test automation framework for hadoop clusters

Tags: hadoop, frameworks, mapreduce, hive, hdfs

I'm looking for system test framework for hadoop clusters. Supported use cases should include system test for HDFS, map reduce jobs and hive queries. I found one from apache which is called [herriot](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6332), but i'm not sure if it's still under maintenance. Are you guys aware of any existing framework?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [1](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/) and [2](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/ecetr/437/) for benchmarking a cluster. It has got both the code and the data for the tests. Automating them shouldn't be much of a task.

Comment: thanks a lot, 2 couldn't be visited, but 1 is definitely informative if I want to build an AF by myself, but i still want to look for other existing ones first

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [HadoopTest](http://web.inf.ufpr.br/pos/RT_DINF002_2013.pdf), a dependability Testing Framework For Hadoop

Answer (score 0):

> Hadoop already having benchmarks and kept in test.jar and example.jars
>   you just have find out and automate. From O'reilly and other books

```
  % hadoop jar $HADOOP/hadoop-*-test.jar
```

> For DFSIO test: TestDFSIO tests the I/O performance of HDFS.
>
> It does this by using a MapReduce job as a convenient way to read or
>   write files in parallel

```
 % hadoop jar $HADOOP/hadoop-*-test.jar TestDFSIO

 command: TestFDSIO -read | -write | -clean [-nrFiles N] [-fileSize MB]
 [-resFile resultFileName] [-bufferSize Bytes] 

 ex1: % hadoop jar $HADOOP/hadoop-*-test.jar TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles
         10 -fileSize 10000 
 ex2: % hadoop jar $HADOOP/hadoop-*-test.jar TestDFSIO -read -nrFiles 10 -fileSize 10000
```

> for testing map reduce

```
   ex3: % hadoop jar  $HADOOP/hadoop-*-examples.jar randomwriter random-data

   ex4: % hadoop jar` $HADOOP/hadoop-*-examples.jar sort random-data sorted-data
```

> where $HADOOP = path to your hadoop installation where these jars kept

Comment: thanks, but this is already mentioned in Praveen's answer above. And i think TestDFSIO uses MiniFSCluster, right?